# Ошибка в загрузке страниц при работе с selenium

Tags: python, selenium, binance

Всем привет. При попытке открыть через silenium Binance, в окне после выполнения проверки на робота (вручную это прохожу, так надо)
Выбивает ошибку [image: После прохождения каждый раз выбивает такую ошибку из-за чего дальнейший вход невозможен]
`driver.get("https://accounts.binance.com/ru/login")`

Подскажите как можно выйти из этой неприятной ситуации, и, быть может, можно через API binance получать доступ к определенной части сайта, чтоб не через Silenium. (пока что в интернете я не нашёл возможности прямого доступа к той части бинанса, которая мне нужна)

Comment: Либо же, как альтернатива, хотелось бы чтобы браузер который открывается, был не "стерильный". а чтоб ранее войдя в аккаунт, открывался браузер с уже залогиненнным аккаунтом. Потому что как я понял, при открытии браузера через selenium, профиль браузера полностью очищается, это не очень удобно.

Answer (score 0):

В итоге разобрался. Оказывается, что браузер/сайт видит когда вы заходите через selenium. Есть много разных способов обхода, но самый простой и эффективный - библиотека Selenium Undetected Chromedriver. Она включает в себя сборку способов обхода детекта, так что пока это лучший вариант который я нашел.